# How do I change start date of 'week()' to Monday instead of Sunday in altair?

Tags: date, altair, dayofweek, days, weekday

I am relatively new to coding and altair, and I am currently struggling to change the start date of 'week()' to begin on Monday instead of Sunday. As a distance runner, I track my weekly mileage from Monday to Sunday instead of the normal Sunday to Monday. I don't think this is a hard issue, but I can't figure it out. I'd appreciate any help!

I tried navigating settings and the date documentation to see if there's a special mondaysunday alternative, but I didn't have any luck.

Comment: In Altair, the start of the week for time units like week() can be adjusted using the timeUnit() function with the week parameter. By default, the start of the week is set to Sunday, but you can change it to Monday by specifying week({startDay: 1})